# Python create a new column with if condition

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I tried to create a new column for my dataset with conditions, however, my jupyter shows the `erroe:ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

Here is my target:

> Create a new column called ‘ind_comp’ that displays either 'Above' or
> 'Below'.  Companies with 'pbk' equal to or higher than 'ind_pbk'
> should have a value‘Above’.  The remainder should be ‘Below’.

And my Codes:

```
def cat(col1,col2):
    if col1-col2>=0:
        result="Above"
    else:
        result= "Below"
    return result

rsh_df['ind_comp']=cat(rsh_df['pbk'],rsh_df['ind_pbk'])
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to do research before asking questions, and look for existing versions of the question - for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+The+truth+value+of+a+Series+is+ambiguous.+Use+a.empty%2C+a.bool()%2C+a.item()%2C+a.any()+or+a.all()).

Comment: Please also try to think carefully about the logic of the problem. How do you want the `cat` function to work? For example, when we set a `result` of `"Above"` or `"Below"`, is that creating an entire column? Or only one cell? Therefore, should the *input* be both entire columns? or just a cell from each column?